# Why does the systemmodstamp for my apex classes update

Tags: apex, class, systemmodstamp

Does anybody know why all the SystemModStamps on my Apex Classes are updating with no other changes to the Classes?

Comment: Anyone changing the API version of classes?

Comment: This happens daily so I don't think that would be it.

Comment: Maybe someone is pushing updates via the metadata api and inadvertently updating all apex classes with exact same code. This is typical in a Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment process.